# Получения параметра в Yii2 Autocomplete от пользователя

Tags: php, ajax, yii2, autocomplete

Здравствуйте!

Стоит такая задача: получить от пользователя страну, и по ее ID получить связанные регионы в ней. Страну получаю через виджет jui\AutoComplete так:

```
        $countries = Country::find()->select('country_name_ru as value, country_name_ru as label, id as id')->asArray()->all();
        <? echo AutoComplete::widget([
            'name' => 'Country',
            'id' => 'country-autocomplete',
            'clientOptions' => [
                'source' => $countries,
                'autoFill'=>true,
                'minLength'=>'4',
                'select' => new JsExpression("function( event, ui ) {
                    $('#addcityform-id_country').val(ui.item.id);
                }")],
        ]);
        ?>
```

Таким образом получаю ID нужной страны в поле #addcityform-id_country.
Теперь нужно получить все регионы конкретно для этой страны.

Основной вопрос именно в этом - как сделать выборку и подгрузку AJAX-ом только этих значений?

Comment: скорее всего копать буду в сторону PJAX

Comment: Удалось решить благодаря:
[ОТВЕТ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27025791/yii2-dependent-autocomplete-widget)